# Manual Equivalent of scope: {value: '&'}?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to manually bind an expression in an attribute in the same manner as an isolated scope with ampersand binds an expression. I can't use an isolated scope for the directive because it is used on elements that already have a new/isolated scope.

Comment: Due to scope inheritance, you can simply call whatever function is defined on the parent scope. For example, say you have `myFunc` defined in the parent scope; your directive can directly call `scope.myFunc()`

Comment: If you don't want to isolate the scope then don't use the scope property inside the directive and use the controller from which you can use event method.

Comment: what did you try to make it? Some piece of code? Plunker?

Comment: I have used $watch for non-functions, however if I use it for a function it just executes it. I can't use scope inheritance to get the function, as the function gets moved around it's storage and I don't want the directive forcing the scope to contain a value of a given name, I want the scope to decide that when it uses the directive.